# If $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f'(0)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> If $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$
>   and $f'(0)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

I know how to show it is continuous but no clue how to show differentiable.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we want to show it is differentiable at a point $p\in\mathbb R$. Note that the given condition implies that $f(0)=1$. (Or $f(0)=0$, but this gives the trivial solution $f=0$).

Then $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)}{h} = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p)f(h)-f(p)}{h} = f(p)\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}\right)=f(p)f'(0).$$

Comment: How did you get from the second to last to the last equality? Why is the limit as h goes to 0 of (f(h)-1/h) equal to the derivative at 0.

Comment: @user110976 It is just the definition of the derivative at $0$. Recall that $f(1)=0$ and that $f(0+h)=f(h)$.

Comment: @Potato How do you get $f(0)=1$? The $\bf 0$ function also works.

Comment: With a little more work, you can show that $f(x)=e^x $, or the $0$ function.

Comment: To user99680: well it is not necessary that $f(x) = e^{x}$. We can also have $f(x) = a^{x}$ for any $a > 0$.

Comment: @GitGud If f(0)=0 then f is identically zero, so there is not much to prove here.

Comment: @studiosus Thanks, I didn't realise that.

Comment: How do i explain that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ implies that $f(0)=1$. I worked it out last night but didn't right it down and now i can't get it

Comment: $f(0+0)=f(0)\cdot f(0)\implies f(0)=(f(0))^2$.